# Which APP or software can revert IFC to JSON

Tags: json, ifc

Just a little question. I mean, JSON is so good in the Web developing. So I try to ask you which APP or software can revert IFC to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFC is a schema built on top of STEP (ISO 10303) format, so thats what would need to be converted, not the IFC aspect. It would be quite trivial to convert STEP syntax to JSON, in fact there is something called IFCxml (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Foundation_Classes#IFC/ifcXML_specifications. ISO 10303-28) which is IFC using XML syntax instead of STEP syntax any way (JSON and XML being somewhat similar in structure, there are many XML -> JSON converters out there).

However there would be no point as this would not change the fact that the IFC still needs to be processed (not just read) by a client with an understanding of the schema. In this regard it makes no difference what syntax is used as the power of the IFC comes from the higher level heirachy of the schema, not the syntax that is used.

It would probably have the same problems as XML for IFC, i.e huge files in comparison to STEP so probably wouldn't be popular, even if there were tools which could process the IFC entities in JSON format.

Comment: Yes! Currently I am using ifcxml file to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Now I find it is a new data format named as ifcjson can deal with it.

It is a new schema, simpler than IFC-SPF and IFCXML.

So maybe we need not a convertor, a new format is also a good choice.